# Old data on Linux raid 1 disks

Tags: linux, raid, mdadm

I have a server with 2 disk in RAID 1. Days ago server runs but disks was mounted on read only mode. I reboot the server and run fcsk command, the problem was solved. Yesterday, server not run at all. I installed another disk and a new linux distro on it, then mounted the RAID using mdadm command into the new disk. That worked fine, but the data inside the RAID are too old (2013). However new data was written from 2012 until yesterday. Is there a way to access all data?

Comment: Could it be possible that your software RAID 1 has been broken for years and the system was writing just to one disk? Try booting from a rescue disk, do *not* run mdadm, then mount, *read-only*, the actual partitions `/dev/sdb1` `/dev/sdc1` etc. of each of the two RAID disks and look at what's there.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick if they're ext4 won't the OP need `mount -o ro,noload`, to avoid replaying any journal?

Comment: Thanks both of you, this command did the trick (mount -o ro,noload /dev/md0). Now I have access to all data.

Comment: Will somebody please post the answer **as an answer** before the question is closed?

Answer (score 2):

1. I've installed new disk (could be a rescue disk too) with a new distribution.
2. I connected one disk an mount it with: `mount -o ro,noload /dev/sdb1` (sometimes works with: `mount -o ro,noload /dev/md0` and both disk mounted).